# How to update code inside textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I have a textarea that will contains a code entered by user and I want to get that code and scan it with jQuery to get the value inside a custom tag called setting then add this value to an input so the user will be able to change the value inside setting tag without touching the code. I was able to get the values and add them inside the inputs but I couldn't update the code with the new values.

HTML CODE :

```
<div id='tab-1'>
  <textarea id='template-code' cols='67' rows='27'></textarea>
  <button id='submit-code'>Submit Code</button>
</div>

<div id='tab-2' class='unactive'>
  <form id='settings-form' method='POST'>
    <div id='result'></div>
    <button id='update-code'>Update Code</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS CODE :

```
.unactive {
    display: none
}
```

jQuery CODE :

```
$('#template-code').change(function (){

  var $that = $(this),
      template_code = $that.val(),
      code = '',
      new_data = '';

  // Extract settings from the theme and add them to #result              
  $(document).on('click', '#submit-code', function (){

      $('#tab-1').addClass('unactive');
      $('#tab-2').removeClass('unactive');

      $(template_code).find('setting').each(function (i){

        var $this = $(this),
            setting_std = $this.text(),
            setting_id = $this.attr('id');

        code += '<input id="'+setting_id+'" name="'+setting_id+'" type="text" value="'+setting_std+'"><br>';

      });

      if(code !== ''){
        $('#result').html(code);
      }

  });

  // Update old data with the new one
  $(document).on('click', '#update-code', function (){

    new_data = $( "#settings-form" ).serializeArray();
    $.each( new_data, function( i, new_field ) {

        template_code += $(template_code).find('setting#'+ new_field.name).text(new_field.value);
        console.log(new_field.value);

    });

    $('#template-code').val(template_code);
    $('#tab-1').removeClass('unactive');

    return false;

  });

});
```

This is an example of the theme code that will be added inside the textarea :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>

    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>

    <div id='option-panel' style='display:none!important'>

      <setting id='post_thumbnail'>http://lorempixel.com/640/300/</setting>
      <setting id='search_icon'>on</setting>

    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a working JsFiddle to make things easier for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/mabwhf6a/3/

This is a small video that explain what I want :

http://screencast.com/t/XqggRlQI6

Comment: Can you make a bit more clear what the issue here is ? Or with which part of the code are you having an issue with?

Comment: @SoorajChandran In the code entered by user there is two setting tag I want to change the value of those tags with new value that the user entered in the inputs.
For example in the code I put there is two values inside setting tag which are : "http://lorempixel.com/640/300/" and "on" when I put the entire code and submit it I get these two values inside input. I want when the user change the value inside input it change inside the theme code so if he change "http://lorempixel.com/640/300/" to "google.com" I want to replace it in the entire code. I hope you understand because my English is bad.

Comment: @SoorajChandran Please see this [video](http://screencast.com/t/XqggRlQI6)

Comment: code in demo is different than in question. Please update question and code to be clear and relevant

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean ? please see this : http://screencast.com/t/XqggRlQI6

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to update old data with the new one:

```
$(document).on('click', '#update-code', function (){
    new_data = $( "#settings-form" ).serializeArray();

    $.each( new_data, function( i, new_field ) {
        var xml = $($.parseXML(template_code));
        xml.find('setting#'+ new_field.name).text(new_field.value);
        template_code = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml[0]);  
    });

    $('#template-code').val(template_code);
    $('#tab-1').removeClass('unactive');

    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robinhuy/jd2hrgn8/

Comment: Your code does change the text but unfortunately it removes XML codes :
http://i.imgur.com/nujsg9T.png

Comment: @masked magician, you will have to treat textarea content as text, on update (and do search/replace), dom manipulation will not give results, it seems - jquery gets confused. :)

Comment: @nevermind Can you tell the principal of your idea and how can apply it because I'm a beginner and I get confused quickly. Thanks

Comment: @maskedmagician, I have updated my code to prevent remove XML elements but after update code, attributes of elements rearranged with your example, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is idea based on, hm... simple search/replace with dynamic regex building (that part could/should be improved, maybe with better regex you can have better solution. I am bad at regex, but also, HTML shouldn't be parsed with regex:)). First part of your code is is as it was... i've changed second function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#update-code', function (){

    //template_code=$('#template-code').val();

for(i=0;i<$('input:text').length;i++)  {

dynamic_regex="(<setting id='"+$('input:text').eq(i).attr('id')+"'>)(.*?)(</setting>)";

var regex = new RegExp(dynamic_regex, 'gm');

var subst = '$1'+ $('input:text').eq(i).val() +'$3'; 
$('#template-code').val($('#template-code').val().replace(regex, subst));

    }

});
```

So, number of text inputs is dynamic (tested on 3 setting tags!), and based on that number (length) and inputs id - we build regex and replace text of tags (line by line) with input values... of course, textarea val must be updated, properly.

Demo:
**http://jsfiddle.net/5zcxbaqf/**