# How to replace text between tags only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple h2 tags and every tag contains text and has a custom attribute called `data-options`. This attribute has multiple options separated by commas and one of these options is the h2 tag text itself.

HTML:

```
<h3 id='test' data-options='happy,sad,fantastic'>sad</h3>
<h3 id='test2' data-options='1,2,3,4'>3</h3>
```

jQuery:

```
var indexArray = ['happy','1'];
$('h3').each(function(i){
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.text(),
        code = $('body').html();

    code = code.replace(value, indexArray[i]);
    $('body').html(code);
});
```

This is what I expect:

```
<h3 id='test' data-options='happy,sad,fantastic'>happy</h3>
<h3 id='test2' data-options='1,2,3,4'>1</h3>
```

Instead  I get this:

```
<h1 id="test" data-options="happy,happy,fantastic">sad</h1>
<h3 id="test2" data-options="1,2,3,4">3</h3>
```

As you can see the script changes the first text it encounters, not the one inside the tags.

This is a working demo for the script : http://jsfiddle.net/fs1sfztx/

Comment: Explain in words what this is supposed to do. rewriting the body isn't making sense. Not clear why the `data-options` exist either. Nothing in your code references them

Comment: This is a peace of a huge code I didn't know how to fix this issue so I posted a question about the issue I had not the whole script.

Comment: How is that supposed to help us understand why the options are there or what they are for? If they weren't relevant you wouldn't have mentioned them but right now there is no connection being made to them

Comment: If you know why the options are there or what they are for won't give any extra value because the problem is clear on the codes I put and I explained what I expect from it.

Comment: But it isn't clear....there is no connection at all in your code to those options so either they aren't relevant and shouldn't have been mentioned or they are relevant and something is missing

Comment: Update question when you finally figure out what is going on. Voting to close this because it is unanswerable currently

Comment: @charlietfl  To clear things a little: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204495/how-to-update-code-inside-textarea-with-jquery This is probably related to this question, i realized when i've seen 'code' var :)... I didn't found better way, because of very specific situation, and since actually HTML parsing is in question, and would like to see better solution, too. Match few lines (one by one!) - replace them with appropriate values.

Comment: let's suppose there is no such thing as data-options just a class with the same value as the text inside the tag how can I solve the problem and change the value between the tags not the one inside the class.

Comment: what was wrong with the answer that @Vohuman gave you?

Comment: @nevermind you are right it is related to the other question. Anyway I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211545/how-to-update-textarea-with-replace-method-through-jquery/32214759)

Comment: Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Pleas try to get your questions organized before asking and wasting people's time. Not saying that in a negative way...just helps us not having misleading issues mixed in.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your advise and next time I will do my best to make things as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to do a replace unless you're searching. Which means you have to be provided what to search for and what to replace it with. So far only the text to in the `h3` is given.

Assuming that each index in `indexArray` matches the index of each `h3` element, then you can compare the current `indexArray` element `indexArray[i]` with each of the words in the corresponding elements `data-options` attribute. When a matches, set the `innerText` prop to that word.

```js
var indexArray = ['happy','1'];
$('h3').text( function( i, txt ) {
    var that = $(this);
    var ntxt = txt;
    $.each( that.data('options').split(','), function( j, u ) {
        indexArray[i] !== u || (ntxt = u);
    });
    return ntxt;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id='test' data-options='happy,sad,fantastic'>sad</h3>
<h3 id='test2' data-options='1,2,3,4'>3</h3>
```

If all you wanted is to play with the `replace` method, then you could use something like this:

```js
var indexArray = ['happy','1'];
var allhtml = $('body').html();
$('h3').each( function( i ) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var re = new RegExp( '>' + txt + '<', 'g' );
    allhtml = allhtml.replace( re, '>' + indexArray[i] + '<' );
});    
$('body').html( allhtml );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id='test' data-options='happy,sad,fantastic'>sad</h3>
<h3 id='test2' data-options='1,2,3,4'>3</h3>
```

Comment: FYI - after a convoluted process of trying to sort this question out OP realized they already had what they needed in another question asked earlier. question really is innacurate compared to what is wanted

Comment: Thanks for the update @charlietfl! Been a long day; must have looked right past the comments.